# How to truncate a FlowDocument

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I would like to prevent the user of my RichTextBox to enter more than a defined number of characters.

So far I managed to get the length of the text using

```
var length = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text.Length;
```

What I want now is to truncate the FlowDocument if the lenght exceed the defined limit. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the text from a pointer defined by your max length and the end of the document.  Then set the text property to empty.

```
int maxLength = ?;
var endPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(maxLength, LogicalDirection.Forward);
var selectionToClear = new TextRange(endPointer, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
selectionToClear.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks @frooook. 
I added a ToList after the Where call, otherwise I get `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified`.
I also added `rtb.Document.Blocks.Remove(rtb.Document.Blocks.Last());` at the end to remove the newly added paragraph (I think). 
I still have to deal with the fact that `GetPositionAtOffset` consider a new line as 1 whereas it is acctually 2 characters (\r\n).

Comment: Actually I may have made this more complicated than it needs to be.  I think you can just select all the text in between endPointer and the end of the document and set that text to string.Empty